# How to define the significance threshold for mutual information in terms of probability of that value occurring in surrogate set?

Tags: correlation

I am trying to assess the significance of the obtained MI matrix. The initial input was a array of 3000 genes by 45 timepoints. MI was computed resulting in a array of 3600 by 3600.  I am thus comparing my results to a shuffled matrix with the same dimensions. I permutate the columns 100 times, thus have 100 results for each element in the matrix. At this stage shall I take the mean for each value in the cell and then overall mean of the matrix MI values to estimate the threshold cutoff? Is taking the mean plus 3SD sensible? Ideally comparison of probability density function between my model and the random should show large discrepancy.

Answer (score 3):

Dawy et al. outline an algorithm in *[Gene mapping and marker clustering using Shannon's mutual information](http://www.ece.iit.edu/~biitcomm/research/references/Zaher%20Dawy/Zaher%20Dawy%202006/Gene%20Mapping%20and%20Marker%20Clustering%20Using%20Shannon%92s%20Mutual%20Information.pdf)* (2006).  If you're using R, you may prefer the [BUS](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.6/bioc/vignettes/BUS/inst/doc/bus.pdf) package in Bioconductor.